# TreeNode Breadth first enum?

Tags: c#, breadth-first-search

Right now my loop is

```
for (TreeNode n = e.Node.FirstNode; n != null; n = n.NextNode)
```

and my data is something like

```
a
    a1
    a2
b
    b1
```

I want to enum breadth only (a, b etc, not a1, a2 etc). How do i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breadth first enumeration is typically done by using a queue of some sort as an ancillary data structure.

First push the root onto the queue.
Then, while there is something in the queue:

- Pop the first item from the front of
  the queue.
- Push its children onto the end of the queue.
- Process the item you popped.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach (TreeNode n in e.Node.Parent.Nodes)
```

you might have to check for a null parent and use

```
TreeNodeCollection nodes;
if(e.Node.Parent != null)
{
    nodes = e.Node.Parent.Nodes;
}
else
{
    nodes = e.Node.TreeView.Nodes;
}
```

This should cover the breadth first algorithm (sorry I haven't tested it)

```
Queue<TreeNode> currentLevel = new Queue<TreeNode>( nodes );
Queue<TreeNode> nextLevel = new Queue<TreeNode>();

while( currentLevel.Count > 0 )
{
    while( currentLevel.Count > 0 )
    {
        TreeNode n = currentLevel.Dequeue();

        // Add child items to next level
        foreach( TreeNode child in n.Nodes )
        {
            nextLevel.Enqueue( child );
        }
    }
    // Switch to next level
    currentLevel = nextLevel;
    nextLevel = new Queue<TreeNode>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify code provided by bstoney
1. push root node to currentLevel queue
2. mark nextLevel = new Queue();

```
        Queue<TreeNode> currentLevel = new Queue<TreeNode>();
        Queue<TreeNode> nextLevel = new Queue<TreeNode>();
        // 1. push root to the queue
        currentLevel.Enqueue(treeView1.Nodes[0]);

        // pop the first item from the front of the queue
        while (currentLevel.Count > 0)
        {
            while (currentLevel.Count > 0)
            {
                TreeNode n = currentLevel.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine(n.Text);

                // Add child items to next level
                foreach (TreeNode child in n.Nodes)
                {
                    nextLevel.Enqueue(child);
                }

            }
            // Switch to next level
            currentLevel = nextLevel;
            // 2. mark this line 
            //nextLevel = new Queue<TreeNode>();
        }
```